# Hilighting multiple div elements placed into each other

Tags: html, css, hover

I have css

```
div{margin-left:15px;}
div:hover{color:red;}
```

and I have multiple divs

```
<div>
 <div>123</div>
 <div>456</div>
    <div>
    <div>789</div>
       <div>
          <div>10 11 12</div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I need that only one div became hilighted when it's under mouse pointer.

Now, when mouse is over any of these, they all become red.

Is it possible with pure CSS code?

Comment: That's some rampant abuse of the `<div>` tag. You should use a more semantically appropriate element, and add classes to the remaining divs indicating their semantic purpose.

Comment: The Problem is, that your cursor is alsways over the top div and all children inherit the color property. As far as I know there is no pure CSS solution to this. But as meagar mentioned you should maybe consider changing your html structure.

Comment: @meagar that means to rewrite some Ks of html code ))

Comment: @lukasgeiter yeah I know it. But JS's onmouseover and -out are equivalent to CSS's `:hover` and they work in this case. I'm just curious is there a pure css colution

Comment: @EL I dont think there is one without changing the html. (e.g. you could wrap every text in a `span` and then style this on hover)

Comment: @lukasgeiter seems hard to complete, because it's generated in recursive function

Comment: @EL Did you get my solution with the `span`? Because I cant see how this could not be possible to add in a recursive function

Comment: @lukasgeiter `function(){$a.="<div>$inc"; if(1){$a.=function();} $a.='</div>'; return $a;}` something like that

Comment: @EL Give me some time, I'll write a proper answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you have so many `div`s, if you want them indented like a list you should use `ul` and `li` but to solve your issue you could wrap all of them in a container and target the `div` hover within that container:

```
.all div:hover{color:red;}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7eE86/1/)

**EDIT**

Just add class names to them and target the class then

[JS](http://jsfiddle.net/7eE86/4/)

Comment: @EL if this is what you are looking for can you please accept this answer

Comment: that works only in case there's one `div` in one `all` wrapper. When it `<div class"all"><div class"all"><div>123` it dooesnt work. But I'll accept your answer as the most appropriate (and only)

Comment: @EL added a new fiddle above

Answer (score 0):

Given the details the OP provided in the comments of the question I would suggest following solution:

I would add a `span` wrapper around every text. So the abstract function that generates the HTML would become this:

```
function(){
    $a.="<div><span>$inc</span>"; // span tag added
    if(1){
        $a.=function();
    }
    $a.='</div>';
    return $a;
}
```

Now the HTML output should look somewhat like this:

```
<div>
 <div><span>123</span></div>
 <div><span>456</span></div>
    <div>
    <div><span>789</span></div>
       <div>
          <div><span>10 11 12</span></div>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which gives the possibility to style it with this CSS:

```
div span:hover {
    color:red;
}
```

Comment: `<span>$inc</span>` not possible, because there're some conditions in this function

Comment: But I need just OP solution. Without assuming the recursion

Comment: @EL Unfortunately I can't think of a CSS only solution, so we will need to change the HTML, therefore recursion matters... Or did I get something wrong?
If not, could you please update your question with the real function?